# Automating Wi-Fi Authorization with Firefox SDK

Tags: firefox, wifi, firefox-addon-sdk, javascript

I'm trying to make a Firefox addon with the Firefox Add-on SDK and API, and I have some questions about their possibilities before I start using them.

My college's Wi-Fi authorization expires every 30 minutes only to have fun pissing off their students. There are already some autofill addons available on many browsers but it's still destructing to move the mouse pointer onto the "Login" button and click it when there is one second left to turn in a midterm paper. I've heard my friends complaining like this for months and I myself think the thing is actually annoying sometimes, so I decided to develop a Firefox addon that takes charge of the job so that the authorization process will feel not even existing once the addon is activated. (I just want to impress my friends honestly.)

For ease I would like to develop the addon within the Firefox add-on SDK. I found that my addon would be utilizing the `page-mod`, `password` and `request` APIs; `page-mod` to detect the Wi-Fi service's auto-redirection into their authorization page, `password` to fill in the page's form by a student ID and password stored in the individual Firefox browser, `request` to redirect the "Login Successful!" page into the originally given destination.

So I guess it should be possible to achieve my goal with this SDK and APIs, but there are still some questions that I need to ask before I proceed:

- Is it possible to pass a callback function to `page-mod::PageMod` (not as a String or a URL to another JavaScript file)? If not, can it be done using the lower level API?
- Is it possible to actually redirect a page in a tab into another page only using high level APIs?
- Is it possible to remember the original destination's location (with the request method and contents) and call it in the process of `page-mod::PageMod` (in order to re-redirect out of the authorization page)? If not, can it be done using the lower level API?
- Is it possible to perform the addon's redirection function on inactive (background) tabs where the opened webpages automatically keep connecting to the Internet and get redirected to the authorization page?

Thank you so much for reading and please spare a little bit of your time for me. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass a callback function to page-mod::PageMod (not as a String or a URL to another JavaScript file)? If not, can it be done using the lower level API?

No, everything that goes through the port is serialized using JSON serialization ([See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/port#emit%28%29)). Instead you would probably emit an event from your content script to execute the callback method with parameters you pass it in the module scope and hardcode parts that need to be done in the content script with port event listeners.

> Is it possible to actually redirect a page in a tab into another page only using high level APIs?

Totally, if you're in a content script, you can just set window.location, or in your modules you set the location of a tab, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#url.

> Is it possible to remember the original destination's location (with the request method and contents) and call it in the process of page-mod::PageMod (in order to re-redirect out of the authorization page)? If not, can it be done using the lower level API?

Possible? Yes, depends a lot on how the redirection from the W-LAN works. Generally all the SDK offers you is getting load/ready events for tabs and reading a tab's current URL. So if you get a ready event at the point of the redirect you're fine. If your college login remembers the redirect target using a get parameter in the URL you're fine. If your college doesn't adjust the URL, you're fine. If you really need to dig through the request, you'll have to ge a bit deeper than even what the SDK offers you, but it is possible.

> Is it possible to perform the addon's redirection function on inactive (background) tabs where the opened webpages automatically keep connecting to the Internet and get redirected to the authorization page?

JS execution for Add-ons is not paused based on a tabs state.

Comment: I took the name wrong :P it was `request`. I corrected the words in my post.

Comment: And thank you for your answer! About passing callback functions to `page-mod`, do they provide any lower APIs that similarly listen to specific locations but can take in more general callback functions, not only to modify page contents using content scripts? Also, what do you mean by `a ready event`? Does it have an access to the address of the original destination when the request is redirected to a specific page?

Comment: Nope, due to security reasons you cannot pass any code down into the page context, the way to do it, is to tell the main script that something has happened on your page and then the main script gives your content script the data it needs to, for example fill in the form.

The ready event for tabs gives you the current tab object, which contains the current URL, that's why it depends on the redirection technique.

Comment: Do you mean that it's fundamentally impossible with the SDK and APIs to execute functions other than content scripts when a tab connects to specific URLs? The authorization process can be done without reading/modifying the HTML but only HTTP requests, so everything would be fine as long as it's possible to detect that a tab is redirected into the authorization page (and to re-redirect the tab into the original destination reading their HTTP response).

Comment: You can execute functions, through listeners of the port API, as mentioned multiple times. Just not in the context of the website but of your extension. To get the original location of the page you could then just track a tab's url and go back to the previous one, once the auth is done. You most likely don't even need page-mode, but can solve it just using the tab events and the request module.